# Read whole appsettings.json file as a string

Tags: json, vb.net, appsettings

I wish to read the entire contents of my `appsettings.json` file into NewtonSoft.JSON so I can parse it using NewtonSoft.

This is due to being able to use full JSON paths with NewtonSoft (filtering etc.)

I basically want to just read my entire `appsettings.json` file as a string.

I already have it working in regardings to a Configuration.

```
Private Shared Function InitConfig() As IConfigurationRoot
            Try
                Dim builder = New ConfigurationBuilder() _
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", True, True) _
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                Return builder.Build
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function
```

However I don't want to choose specifics i.e. `config("test1:test:bot_token")`. I wish to just read the entire string, however I don't appear to be able to get this from the ConfigurationRoot.

Cheers

Comment: Sounds good, what have you tried and what isn't working? Please update your post to include code so we can further help you.

Comment: @Codexer - Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Went about this all the wrong way - just used a streamreader to read the appsettings.json file.

Complete brain fart moment.

```
Dim tr As TextReader = New StreamReader("appsettings.json")
Dim stream = tr.ReadToEnd
```